# how to sort custom attribute members in a cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

We have a cube with many measures and one of the main dimensions is an account dimension with about a dozen accounts.

Instead of using hierarchies to rollup from subaccounts to accounts to summary accounts, my users want me create some custom dimension attribute members to sum up sub account transactions, and account transactions:

for example:

instead of
Summary Account-A  600
Account-A1 100
Account-A2 200
Account-A3 300
Summary Account-B 250
Account-B1 120
Account-B2 130

they want:

```
   Account-A1 100
   Account-A2 200
   Account-A3 300
   Summary Account-A  600

   Account-B1 120
   Account-B2 130
   Summary Account-B 250
```

I created Custom attribute members in SSAS. but now my problem is how do i sort these custom attribute members with other normal members in the order my users want?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless we add other prefix of the attributes , they are sorted alphabetically. Unfortunately We could not set the members order.